# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_loggedin() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\login.php:5 Stack trace: #0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a school project, and I get this error and notice when I try to test my login.php and signup.php pages.

For signup.php:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\signup.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_loggedin() on unknown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\signup.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\signup.php on line 3

And for login.php:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\login.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_loggedin() on unknown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\login.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SneakerTrade\login.php on line 5

I have a set of public functions in a file called Class.User.php set up that are to be used with the signup, login, and home pages. When writing the code, it compiles just fine. I have tried to fix a few things here and there, but I am still new to PHP and PDO, and so I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my Class.User.php:

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');

class USER
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    public function register($firstName,$lastName,$Username,$email,$Password)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstName,lastName,Username,email,Password)
                                                       VALUES(:firstName, :lastName, :Username, :email, :Password)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":Username", $Username);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":Password", $new_password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":firstName", $firstName);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lastName", $lastName);
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($Username,$email,$Password)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username=:Username OR email=:email LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute(array(':Username'=>$Username, ':email'=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                if(password_verify($Password, $userRow['Password']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['UserSession'] = $userRow['UserId'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['UserSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['UserSession']);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Connect.php, if it helps:

```
<?php
// $user = 'root';
// $pass = '';
// $db = new PDO ( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sneakertrade', $user, $pass );
class Database
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "sneakertrade";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}

?>
```

signup.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['signUp']))
{
   $Username = trim($_POST['userName']);
   $email = trim($_POST['email']);
   $Password = trim($_POST['password']); 

   if($Username=="") {
      $error[] = "Please Provide A UserName"; 
   }
   else if($email=="") {
      $error[] = "Please Provide An Email"; 
   }
   else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $error[] = 'Please Enter A Valid Email Address';
   }
   else if($Password=="") {
      $error[] = "Please Provide A Password";
   }
   else if(strlen($Password) < 6){
      $error[] = "Password Must Be At Least 6 Characters"; 
   }
   else
   {
      try
      {
         $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT Username, email FROM users WHERE Username=:Username OR email=:email");
         $stmt->execute(array(':Username'=>$Username, ':email'=>$email));
         $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

         if($row['Username']==$Username) {
            $error[] = "This User Already Exists";
         }
         else if($row['email']==$email) {
            $error[] = "This Email Is Already In Use";
         }
         else
         {
            if($user->register($FirstName,$Lastname,$Username,$email,$Password)) 
            {
                $user->redirect('signup.php?joined');
            }
         }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
  } 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sign Up</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Index Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Animate.css -->
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this website -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1 id="loginPrompt">Sign Up</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
        action="signup.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">First
                Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName2"
                    name="firstName" placeholder="John">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName2"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName2"
                    name="lastName" placeholder="Doe">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUserName"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserName"
                    name="userName" placeholder="JDoe">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                    name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3"
                    name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" name="signUp" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h3 id="signUpMessage"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $Username = $_POST['email'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $Password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($Username,$email,$Password))
    {
        $user->redirect('home.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Your Credentials Are Incorrect.";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Landing Page">
    <meta name="author" content="Jordan C. McRae">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Login Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this website -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1 id="loginPrompt">Log In</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, I am still very new to PHP and PDO, and I have been trying to figure this out for hours, but to no avail. Could anyone help me with this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't have the variable `$user` in signup.php, that's why you can't call it.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).